# Retarding Potential?

Tags: electromagnetism, photoelectric-effect

Concerning the photoelectric effect, my textbook never defines what retarding potential is, and the internet isn't really clear on it either. I'm getting the sense that retarding potential is just the potential of an EM field, but why is it specifically labeled "retarding"? Is it decreasing with time or something?

Comment: See http://www.citycollegiate.com/physicsXII_17a.htm; your guess is very close to the correct meaning.  You adjust the retarding potential until you find the actual value where the current starts.

Comment: So it's not really one single value, nor it's not something that can be expressed in a nice formula, but it's just that a person doing the experiment adjusts this potential however he/she likes?

Answer (score 1):

Retarding potential is not related specifically to change in time. It is related to **polarity** of the field. A retarding potential is rejecting photoelectrons from reaching the receiving electrode. So it will be negative on the receiving electrode compared to the photoelectrode. If its extremely negative, it will reject **all** photoelectrons and circuit current will cease.

As opposed to retarding potential, you have accelerating potential with opposite voltage drop.